# Migrate customer and order data from M2 to M1

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, importexport

We are migrating a Magento2 site to Magento1
What would be the best way to get customer and order data over from Magento2 to Magento1?
Should we build an API bridge or are the database tables similar enough that we can just do a dump and import?

Comment: How many SKU do you have?

Comment: the SKU's are all done already, it's the customer and order data that I want to   migrate

Comment: My bad. Sorry. That is going to be difficult. Will let you know if something else than "by hand" comes to mind.

Comment: why do you want to migrate data from M2 to M1 while the M1 support end date is coming so close?

Comment: @LitExtensionMagentoMigration That question was asked 3 years ago when M2 wasn't as stable...

Answer (score 1):

You should try ubertheme tool for data migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2. here's the link for this tool.

https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-news/magento-2-data-migration-tool/

Below link will also help you if you have any confusion in above link.

https://magecomp.com/blog/migrating-magento-1-x-to-magento-2-0/

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use Magento 1. If you don't want to use Magento 2, You should move to another platform. Because Magento 1 is ending for a [long time ago](https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/support-magento-1-software-ends-june-30-2020). It means your website will don't get any updated security. A lot of Magento 1 website got an attack that way. Some week ago, one of our customer got attack(they use Magento 1), they lost all data.